# Is cropping and rescaling background a good solution for java games?

Tags: java, image, 2d-games

I'm very new to java and I'm currently developping a 2D game.
I'm trying to use Java Swing for the graphics and I have a problem doing so :

Displaying the background, which is a fairly high definition image, (currently 2000x2000 but will grow bigger for higher definition), with a map of 50 units in width and height.

The problem is that I don't want to display the whole map but only a fixed amount of cells in width and height of it (here i chose 20). I first tried to rescale the image wider than the screen to make the 20 cells fit perfectly (a bit like a zoom on the area we want) and then draw it with an offset related to the player's position (which is always displayed on the centered of the screen).

But while i try to go with bigger images, i get a java heap space memory exception.

So i was thinking of getting a cropped version of the image and then rescale it to the screen's dimension to have a smaller rescaled image. I'm not getting exceptions any more but I have some important performances issues with a drop of 30 fps.

I was also thinking about getting all cropped images possible and storing them but I wanted to know if that's a thing or not.

To sum up, I was wondering what were the best ways to display a background in games.
Since 2D games or even 3D games have maps even larger than I do, I think I must be missing something, I don't get how to display sprites with high resolution while keeping a decent frame rate.
Thank your for your time.

edit:

To put a bit of context : The map is a big maze and the player should only be able to see a local view of the maze. And because I would want a rather detailed Background, i have to be able to display large images.

Here is a reduced view of my code sample :

```
public class Background implements Drawable, Anchor {
    private final String name;
    private final Image image;
    private final int width;


    public Background(String name){
        this.name = name;
        BufferedImage image = FileSystem.readBufferedImage(GraphicType.BACKGROUND, name);
        //image is a 2000x2000 image
        this.image = image.getScaledInstance((int)(behavior.width()
                * (Game.frame.getWidth()/(double) Settings.NB_CELLS_ON_SCREEN_WIDTH)),
                -1,
                0
        );
        //result in a 19200x19200 image
        this.width = (int)(behavior.width()
                * (Game.frame.getWidth()/(double)Settings.NB_CELLS_ON_SCREEN_WIDTH));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(
                image,
                -8640,
                -9060,
                null);

    }

}
```

With the GraphicPosition class computing the position on screen, with the following arguments in constructor : An anchor object, an xOffset and a yOffset

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to comment.  Make sure you are doing nothing but painting in the paintComponent method of your drawing panel.  If you would create a [mre] that shows the problem, it would be helpful.

Comment: Can you make a reproducable example of what gives you an out of memory error if you have a 2k x 2k image? The Graphics class has methods for drawing a section of one image, eg your 4MP image, onto another image. You do not need to create a scaled copy.

Comment: Also there isn't a prescribed system that works for everything. Prescaled images are definitely a thing, such as MipMap https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap but your first error sounds like your producing a second image that is massive, when all you really need to do is call graphics.drawImage with the appropriate argument selection.

Comment: While using the same piece of code i wrote in my post, with the x argument in the drawImage method resulting in -8640, y resulting in -9060 and width in 19200, i get this java heap space exception with a 2000x2000 image.

Comment: Maybe you should update your code to illustrate that. Which image is 2kx2k?

Comment: Are you saying `image.getScaledInstance` results in an image 19200x19200? You definitely shouldn't be creating that scaled image.

Comment: Taking your advice into account, I played a bit with the code and it seems that using the  drawImage(Image img, int dx1, int dy1, int dx2, int dy2, int sx1, int sy1, int sx2, int sy2, ImageObserver observer), instead of using a separate scaling method makes the thing a lot more fluid

Comment: I think if you include the code in your answer, it would have been a good question/ answer pair. Not sure why you deleted.

Comment: Truth being told, i'm trying to figure out the right calculations for it to work on my game before republishing the answer, because i'm getting some weird visuals for the moment. I'll do it in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

I now draw the background using the [drawImage(Image img, int dx1, int dy1, int dx2, int dy2, int sx1, int sy1, int sx2, int sy2, ImageObserver observer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) 
As matt suggested, it causes a less significant fps drop because i'm no longer creating a huge temporary image and the good thing about this solution is that the difference in frame rate with bigger images seems to be small.

Here is the code I used and worked for me :

public class Foreground implements Drawable {

```
private final String name;
private final BufferedImage image;
private final Behavior behavior;
private final int width;

public Foreground(String name, Behavior behavior){
    this.name = name;
    this.image = FileSystem.readBufferedImage(GraphicType.FOREGROUND, name);
    this.behavior = behavior;
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    /*This variable represents the width on the image of the number of cells
    In my code its is the width on the image of 20 cells*/
    int widthOnImageForNbCellsDisplayed = (image.getWidth()/behavior.width()) * Settings.NB_CELLS_ON_SCREEN_WIDTH;

    /*This posXInImage represents the position of the top left corner of the
    area of the image we want to draw*/
    int posXInImage = (int)(
            Game.player.posX()
                    * image.getWidth()
                    / (double)behavior.width()
                    - widthOnImageForNbCellsDisplayed/2
    );
    int posYInImage = (int)(
            Game.player.posY()
                    * image.getHeight()
                    / (double)behavior.height()
                    - widthOnImageForNbCellsDisplayed/2
    );
    /*Here is struggled with the fact that the position of the second 
    coordinates is absolute and not relative to the first coordinates
    ,what I was originally thinking*/
    g.drawImage(image,
            0,
            -(Game.frame.getWidth() - Game.frame.getHeight())/2,
            Game.frame.getWidth(),
            Game.frame.getWidth()-(Game.frame.getWidth() - Game.frame.getHeight())/2,
            posXInImage,
            posYInImage,
            posXInImage + widthOnImageForNbCellsDisplayed,
            posYInImage + widthOnImageForNbCellsDisplayed,
            null);
}
```

}